# How to get objectName of a pyqtgraph plotwidget during a mouse wheelEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt5, mouseevent, mousewheel, pyqtgraph

I am trying to identify the object name of a pyqtgraph plotwidget I am mouse wheeling on. However, I can only seem to get the object id "PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget object at 0x0000018ED2ED74C8". If I use the QApplication.widgetAt(event.globalPos()).objectName I get nothing, even though I have set the object name. Can you help me?

Sample code:

```
# Import packages
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.graphLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.graph = pg.PlotWidget(name="graph1")
        self.graph.setObjectName("graph1")
        self.graphLayout.addWidget(self.graph)

        self.setLayout(self.graphLayout)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        hoveredWidget = QApplication.widgetAt(event.globalPos())
        print(hoveredWidget.objectName())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PlotWidget is actually a subclass of QAbstractScrollArea, which is a complex widget that has at least three children widgets: the scroll bars (even when they're hidden) and, most importantly, the [*viewport*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#details), which actually is the "content" of the scroll area.

This means that using `widgetAt()` you are not getting the plot widget (the scroll area), but its viewport. In fact, in your case you can get the plot widget by checking the parent:

```
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        hoveredWidget = QApplication.widgetAt(event.globalPos())
        if hoveredWidget and hoveredWidget.parent():
            print(hoveredWidget.parent().objectName())
```

Be careful when intercepting events from a parent widget, especially for widget as complex as scroll areas: it's not guaranteed that you will receive them, as the children could [accept](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#accepted-prop) them, preventing further propagation to their parent(s).

If you need more control over them, it's usually better to implement the respective methods in their subclasses or installing an [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on the instances.
Note that, for the reason above, if you want to filter events on a scroll area you might prefer to install the filter on the viewport:

```
    self.graph.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
```